# Get a $_POST to php from Jquery HandsonTable()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to javascript/jquery/ajax. 
I'm trying to get the data from a jquery handsonTable (http://handsontable.com/index.html) into my php code.

I compute a table from a mysql database then display it using php to build the jquery code.

Now i'd like to be able to get the user modified table, get the post when submitted from a form and inject it using php.

Here is a test code below, where I try to send a $_POST from the jquery to save.php.
The problem is I get nothing out of the test.php.

Is there any easy way to get a nice $_POST to a php file from a handsonTable?
Thanks, and sorry for the dumb questions, I'm all new to it, I looked over here for an answer but nothing worked for me so that's why I'm asking.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
var_dump($_POST);
?>

<script src="../lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">

<form action="save.php" id="searchForm" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="test" name="test">

<pre id="console" class="console">console</pre>

<div id="dateTable"></div>

<script>


var $console = $("#console");
var $container = $("#dateTable");

  var data = [
{day:"Th 1", p1:"",p2:""},
{day:"Fr 2", p1:"",p2:""},
{day:"Sa 3", p1:"",p2:""}
  ];

$container.handsontable({
    data: data,
});

$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $( this ),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  var post = JSON.stringify({"data":handsontable.getData()});
  var posting = $.post( url, post );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $console.empty().append( post );
  });
});


</script>

</form>
```

Comment: encapsulate your jquery code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //Your jquery code goes here  };)`

Comment: If I do this, the handsonTable spreadsheet is no longer displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button doesn't have the ID of "test", it only has a name of "test". Set the ID and it should post to your web server.

To clarify: the name property is usually only usable for forms, because input elements will have a "name" and a "value" property - forming a name/value pair with the submitted data. To use jQuery to effectively select one unique element on your page, use the ID of that element - which you haven't set in your code.

I am not sure if you are familiar with the built-in browser developer tools, but that is what you need (teach a man how to fish, etc.) Test your javascript first, I recommend using Chrome and hitting F12 to get to the developer tools.

The Network tab will tell you all you need to know about the requests to and from your browser, and it will tell you exactly what is (not) being sent when you submit your form. You can place breakpoints in your javascript code as well, to show you why a function doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: That was actually a Typo, hasty copy/paste into StackOverFlow, I edited the code, thanks! The actual code seems to send something though, because the console div returns the js post variable. Thanks for the tips anyway :)

Comment: And the network tab in the developer tools, does it tell you what is being sent? You'll see a request to your web server with the data which is encoded as form data.